# Getting text over a image

Tags: html, css

Have created a full screen image, that is filling the full site when you enter my website. But I can't make text over the image so that I can have a read more button and a welcome to name.

This is my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12-">
        <img class="img-responsive" style="min-height: 100%; min-width: 1024px; width: 100%; height: auto; position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; " src="~/Content/img/maxresdefault%20(1).jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions on how I add text over an image?

It needs to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `position` property value of `absolute`, and a positive z-index property value  to the text container only. See the example below and adjust as needed.

```css
.row  {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  }

.col-md-12 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  }

.col-md-12 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  }




.text {
  position: absolute; /* Make stack-ability possible */
  z-index: 3;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.70;
  padding: 10px;
  ;
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-12">

  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvCoo.jpg">
    
    </div>
  
  
  <div class="text">   Whatever your text is goes here </div>
  
  <div>
```

Comment: want it like fx this. http://csgopredict.dk/ so that the image fill 100% of screen width and height

Comment: Dosen't work, it gives it a padding on rightsite with like 10px annd then it dosen't go 100% :)

Comment: Fixed it added the code i used first from col-md-12 and then also added you div with text so nnow it worked :) Thannks for the help :)

Answer (score 3):

There are a few ways:

- div with text inside and `style="background: url('my_img.png');"`.
- a div with 'position: absolute; z-index: -1;' behind it that contains the img or background img.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do it, the second option IMO is the simplest.

1. Positioned absolute
2. Offset from top with margin and center aligned button/content

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbBVeB

```
body{
  background: url(http://placehold.it/1600x900);
}

.welcome{
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with the background-image method your CSS code would be:

```
body{
background-image: url('~/Content/img/maxresdefault%20(1).jpg');
background-position: center;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

put that on  CSS and you're done!